# I cannot rm -rf this directory Permission denied even though I have perm WSL2 ubuntu

Tags: permissions, chmod, chown, rm, neovim

So there is this location `~/.local/share/nvim/mason/.packages`
for mason to properly install packages it apparently needs to be able to remove stuff within this folder

however my user doesn't have perm to delete this as manually doing `rm -rf .packages` returns these errors:

```
rm: cannot remove '.packages/typescript-language-server/node_modules/typescript/lib/zh-cn/diagnosticMessages.generated.json': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '.packages/typescript-language-server/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2020.date.d.ts': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '.packages/typescript-language-server/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2017.object.d.ts': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '.packages/typescript-language-server/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2023.array.d.ts': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '.packages/typescript-language-server/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.webworker.iterable.d.ts': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '.packages/typescript-language-server/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.d.ts': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '.packages/typescript-language-server/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2017.string.d.ts': Permission denied
```

however I have used: `sudo chown cyneptic:cyneptic .packages` - to get perm and the perm shows
`drwxr-xr-x 7 cyneptic cyneptic 4096 Apr 14 01:32` .

but I can't delete it as cyneptic.

waltinator's pathlld output:

```
drwxr-xr-x 19 root root 4096 Apr 14 09:42 /
/dev/sdb on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,discard,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr 13 18:02 /home
drwxr-x--- 13 cyneptic cyneptic 4096 Apr 14 09:58 /home/cyneptic
drwx------ 4 cyneptic cyneptic 4096 Apr 13 21:44 /home/cyneptic/.local
drwx------ 3 cyneptic cyneptic 4096 Apr 13 21:44 /home/cyneptic/.local/share
drwx------ 4 cyneptic cyneptic 4096 Apr 14 09:57 /home/cyneptic/.local/share/nvim
drwxr-xr-x 7 cyneptic cyneptic 4096 Apr 14 02:12 /home/cyneptic/.local/share/nvim/mason
drwxr-xr-x 2 cyneptic cyneptic 4096 Apr 14 02:21 /home/cyneptic/.local/share/nvim/mason/.packages
```

Comment: Either the partition is mounted Read-Only, or you don't have Write permission for the parent directory. Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with `https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld`, a `bash` script to show the permissions, mount options along the path to an object or objects.

Comment: edited the output in the original post as it didn't fit in the comments.